# Import CSV into Database using Pymysql Python 3

Tags: python

I couldn't understand while file is not considered by the interpreter

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('D:\\Eclipse_Python\\Python\\com\\praveen\\pandas\\iplStats.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    cur.execute('PREPARE stmt FROM INSERT INTO praveendb.iplstats (Wins,Losses,Year,Loss,Team) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', row)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Eclipse_Python\Python\pandasLibDataFrame.py", line 28, in <module>
    csv_data = csv.reader(file('D:\\Eclipse_Python\\Python\\pandas\\iplStats.csv'))
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are suing Python 3. If you are using Python 3. `File()` is not availabe instead use `open()`

```
import csv

with open('yourfile.csv') as csv_file:
    do you code
```

Comment: in addition to what @Backtrack said, use `with` context manager - both for reading the file and connecting to the database